# Simple explanation of DSL in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I referred [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html), [this](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I am confused actually.

I am not sure DSL is something to SQL i.e the way we query the data in elastic search called DSL?

OR

There are many ways to access data in elastic search. One of them is DSL. I don't think so this is true.

OR

There was some python wrapper which is more simplified to access the data in elastic search - This is really confusing

Could anyone please tell me the ways of accessing data and what is DSL, how is it related?

I understand that this is very basic question. I couldn't find proper explanation on any of the places or when I refer more I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR the python DSL is a high-level wrapper around a low-level py wrapper of the search API.

---

ES is a JSON-in, JSON-out interface but there are multiple ways of sending requests. Here's my own list, ordered by ease of use AND flexibility:

1. POST [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) w/ payload

```
GET abc/_search?version=true
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

2. Python [Low](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) Level Client

```
es.get(index="my-index", id=42)['_source']
```

3. [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)

```
http://localhost:9200/index/_search
```

4. Python [High](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html) Level Client

```
s = Search().using(client).query("match", title="python")
```