# Elasticsearch: highlight on query terms, not filter terms?

Tags: python, dictionary, elasticsearch, querying

Say I have this:

```
search_object = {
    'query': { 
        'bool' : { 
            'must' : { 
                'simple_query_string' : { 
                    'query': search_text,
                    'fields': [ 'french_no_accents', 'def_no_accents', ],
                },  
            },
            'filter' : [ 
                { 'term' : { 'def_no_accents' : 'court', }, },
                { 'term' : { 'def_no_accents' : 'bridge', }, },
            ],
              
        },
    },
    'highlight': {
        'encoder': 'html',
        'fields': {
            'french_no_accents': {},
            'def_no_accents': {},
        },
        'number_of_fragments' : 0,
    },        
}
```

... whatever search string I enter as `search_text`, its constituent terms, but also "court" and "bridge" are highlighted. I don't want "court" or "bridge" to be highlighted.

I've tried putting the "highlight" key-value in a different spot in the structure... nothing seems to work (i.e. syntax exception thrown).

More generally, is there a formal grammar anywhere specifying what you can and can't do with ES (v7) queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [highlight query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html#highlighting-settings) to limit what should and shouldn't get highlighted:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "abc",
          "fields": [
            "french_no_accents",
            "def_no_accents"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "def_no_accents": "court" } },
        { "term": { "def_no_accents": "bridge" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "encoder": "html",
    "fields": {
      "*_no_accents": {                    <--
        "highlight_query": {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "abc",
            "fields": [ "french_no_accents", "def_no_accents" ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_fragments": 0
  }
}
```

I've used a wildcard for the two fields (`*_no_accents`) -- if that matches unwanted fields too, you'll need to duplicate the highlight query on two separate, non-wilcard highlight fields like you originally had. Though I can't think of a scenario where that'd happen since your `multi_match` query targets two concrete fields.

---

As to:

> More generally, is there a formal grammar anywhere specifying what you can and can't do with ES (v7) queries?

what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I simply mean: how do you know what's legal and what isn't in these query objects? (or for that matter JSON objects used in all contexts in Elasticsearch). By the way, you might just have the knowledge to answer my other highlighter question asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66126168/595305

Comment: NB have just signed up for your handbook!

Comment: Thanks for signing up! So what's legal and what's not is usually defined in the official documentation (as I linked in the above answer). There's no *single* syntax resource. If you provide invalid syntax, ES will throw an exception which, I must admit, is not always helpful... I'm gonna go check your other question -- let's see if I can help.